# Query property name within property getter and setter method

Tags: python

there is a generic function to create properties. It returns the property getter and setter.

See e.g. line 205.

https://github.com/pymeasure/pymeasure/blob/master/pymeasure/instruments/instrument.py

This function is used to create properties.

See e.g. line 90

https://github.com/pymeasure/pymeasure/blob/master/pymeasure/instruments/agilent/agilent34450A.py

I need to change the attributes, e.g. ":READ?" to be replaced by ":MEAS:DC:CURR?", of the property at runtime, to e.g. support different instruments having the same property but different property attributes. I need to do this for the object and not for the class because I want to use different instruments at the same time, so same class but different objects.

In order to generically identify the attribute to be replaced and, for example, to select it from a data class, it would be nice if the property getters and setters could query the name of the property in which they were called.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You should write the few lines of your code code related to the question. Not just inclure all your code. See [MRE]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

These are class attributes, so you should be able to reassign them after instantiating the class. For example, something like:

```
instrument = Agilent34450A(Instrument)
instrument.current = Instrument.measurement(":MEAS:DC:CURR?", """new description""")
```